# Bootstrap dropdown item clicked, change button class using toggleClass Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

Currently I have multiple buttons on my website, these components are using bootstrap. When each button is clicked, a drop-down appears with different priorities dependent on the button the user selects. I am trying to find a way to update the button class to match the priority selected.

For example priorities against bootstrap component class:

1. High priority is bootstrap class: btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle
2. Medium priority is bootstrap class: btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle
3. Low priority is bootstrap class: btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle
4. Service request priority is bootstrap class: btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle

HTML code:

```
    <div id="tableBody"><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">High</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW"  class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Medium</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="LOW"  class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Low</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ServiceRequest</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW" 
      class="dropdown-item">Low</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW" 
      class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST"  class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">High</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW"  class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Medium</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="LOW"  class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Low</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST" 
      class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ServiceRequest</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW" 
      class="dropdown-item">Low</a></div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><a datapriority="HIGH"  class="dropdown-item">High</a><a datapriority="MEDIUM"  class="dropdown-item">Medium</a><a datapriority="LOW" 
      class="dropdown-item">Low</a><a datapriority="SERVICEREQUEST"  class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></div>
</div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
        //update priority
$("#tableBody").on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(e) {
      var priority = $(this).attr("datapriority");
  console.log(priority);
    //issue I am having is below
    if (priority == "HIGH") {
      console.log("first: " + priority);
      object.toggleClass('btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    } else if (priority == "MEDIUM") {
      console.log("second: " + priority);
      object.toggleClass('btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    } else if (priority == "LOW") {
      console.log("third: " + priority);
      object.toggleClass('btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    } else if (priority == "SERVICEREQUEST") {
      console.log("fourth: " + priority);
      object.toggleClass('btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
    @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I also want to ensure the text on the button changes to represent what priority it is that was selected. Also I want to ensure only when one button is clicked, only that button should update not all buttons that match that class.

If the above is unclear I am happy to try explain with more details.

Example:

1. User clicks on first 'High' button which is currently the class bt button danger
2. User selects medium from the drop down
3. Button has now changed to the text 'Medium' and has the class 'btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle' and should now have the drop down choices as 'High', 'Low' and 'Service Request'

Jfiddle also here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lohjzvqc/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some additional info to button (such as id) and to your dropdown options. For example:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">High</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
<li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
<li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
```

Then next script change button style and text by choosing option in select (it uses option text comparsion, so data-priority tag is unnecessary, but you can rewrite script to use it)

```
$('a[name=priority]').on('click',function() {
  const btn = $('#btn');
  const selectedPrior = $(this);
  switchPriority(btn, selectedPrior);
  switchBtnStyle(btn);
});

function switchPriority(currentPriorBtn, newPriorA){
    const btnText = currentPriorBtn.text();
  const aText = newPriorA.text();
  newPriorA.text(btnText);
  currentPriorBtn.text(aText);
}

function switchBtnStyle(btn){
    const btnText = btn.text();
  btn.removeClass();
  switch(btnText){
    case 'High':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'Low':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'Medium':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'ServiceRequest':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
  }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmww8t4L/)

Comment: Does this mean, for each button I have to create an ID for the button and an ID for the items in the drop down list? And then an onclick for each item in the drop down list?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mmww8t4L/4/ 

E.g. this wouldnt work by adding a new button in using the same IDs

Comment: In this solution - yes, but you can use .nearest or .parent specs of jquery to find near to dropdown button w/o adding any id's. 

From other side, if you have similar dropdown menu to each button, you can use just one menu, which'll be opened on every button click. And before dropdown open you can progtammatically show or hide menu items which you dont want to see

Comment: @RA19
you need to change this: `const btn = $('#btn');` to this `const btn = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('button');`. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/9ghx291f/1/